# Export workbook data from different files to SP 2013 list

Tags: list, excel

I have a main site from which new subsites are created whenever a new project is started. In each of these sites there's an Excel standard document where people fill in data about that specific project.

My goal is to create a database list in the main site that is automatically update with the content from those Excel files located in each project subsite.

I've seen many ways to transfer data from Excel to a list, but none of them worked so far.

Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... How about adding VBA code to the Excel document? On save, it will sync its content with the SharePoint list on the main site. You'll obviously need to convert the Excel file to .xlsm if it's not already in that format.

Comment: I'm a bit new to VBA coding Wonderwalrus. Could you give me more details on how to program this on VBA?

Comment: Here are some resources: Basic CRUD operations from Excel VBA: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/bc445ec5-6514-4da3-9101-7ef1a3c3fbd6/how-to-do-crud-operations-using-rest-api-from-excel-vba-; SharePoint List REST API Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx; SharePoint 2013 REST Syntax (wall poster): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41147